# Is there someone to explain double IP Header in UDP?

Tags: udp, ip, sip, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

[image]

I got a upper pcap.

This pcap show me the double IP header.

```
10.10.10.10 -> 10.10.10.50
10.25.85.3 -> 10.25.87.52
```

I don't know why contain double IP header..

And I don't know when this used.

Is there someone to explain double IP Header in UDP?

Comment: Can you upload the pcap somewhere?

Comment: yes. pcap is here. https://www.cloudshark.org/captures/82506ab125bd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the first IP header is protocol 4 (IP-in-IP) which is the encapsulation RFC https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2003 thus it carries another IP layer inside sort of a tunnel/VPN. The second IP header is normal UDP and from there everything continues normally. I am not sure if Wireshark is giving you a glitch parsing such packets when they are fragmented because some of the context in missing, however no mystery overall. You have encapsulation configured somewhere. It could be an artefact of your capture tool configuration.